# Multiple Filtering in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter my data using 2 columns and 2 different filter requirements.

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="yes"
ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Low"
```

If I filter by either "yes" or "Low" separately it works.  However, if I try and filter range K2-ZZ200 by "yes" and then Column E by "Low" it seems to hide everything.

How can I filter by both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the same `Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200")` for both [`AutoFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb242013%28v=office.12%29.aspx) statements:

```
' Column A = Field 1
ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="yes"
' Column E = Field 5
ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Low"
```

Also, you may need to set `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I think you might also have to make sure that the field number is different but I could be wrong. (in his question they are the same.)

Comment: Ok I've updated but still no joy. I need to set the filter mode to false at the start so it removes all existing filters and then performs the filter

Comment: You should probably try to `Record Macro` and repeat the steps to filter the worksheet. Then inspect the generated code to see what you are missing. However, it usually generates ugly code - just use the code for reference. For example, in Office 2007/2010 you might need to add a parameter in AutoFilter `Operator:=xlFilterValues` (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839625.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  Managed to do this using an array.  The Range does not need to be the same by the way.

```
     ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=nice, Criteria1:="yes"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Filter 1", ""Filter 2", "On "Filter 3", ""Filter 4", ""Filter 5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```